# Pluck multiple and/or nested fields on mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, moped

I have the following query db in mongodb that returns exactly what I need:

```
 db.collection.find({field1: 2801394}, {name: 1, field2: 1, _id: 1, "field3.2801394": 1})
```

Note field 3 is a hash, and the key used here is the same as for field1 by the value in field 1.

How can I convert this query to mongoid?  There are two main issues here, and I can't find anything online for either one individually:

1. I can't figure out the syntax for both plucking two fields at once
2. I can't find the syntax for plucking a nested field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

For filtering out/projecting one or more fields, you can use Queryable.only found at http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/options.html.

The example given on that page:

```
queryable.only(:name, :age)
```

For nested fields, you could use strings instead of symbols in the parameters:

```
queryable.only(:name, :field2, :_id, 'field3.2801394')
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `pluck` for both of your issues:

- For plucking two fields at once:

  `Model.where(conditions).pluck(:field1, :field2)`
- For plucking a nested field:

  `Model.where(conditions).pluck('field.nested_field')`

---

- Bonus: You could also do this if you want a field and a nested field of some other field:

  `Model.where(conditions).pluck(:field1, 'field2.nested_field')`
- And, even this is possible:

  `Model.where(conditions).pluck('field.one.two')`

  where `two` is nested field of `one` which in turn is the nested field of `field`.

Also, the "field" could be a `String`, `Symbol` or `Array` according to it's documentation: [Mongoid::Contextual::Mongo#pluck](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Contextual/Mongo:pluck)

Answer (score 1):

Mongoid has a `pluck` function now.

[mongoid#pluck](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Contextual/Mongo:pluck)

Example:

```
Model.where(conditions).pluck(:specific_field)
```

Comment: unless you care about duplicates you should use `#distinct` instead of `#pluck`

See that question for more: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37333137/2047418