# pluck vs distinct in mongoid db. which is faster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

It seems that mongodb has two equivalent methods:

[#pluck](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Contextual/Mongo:pluck) and [#distinct](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/moped/Moped%2FQuery%3Adistinct) which both return only given fields from a collection.

so both

```
User.pluck(:name)
User.distinct(:name)
```

would return array of all names from User collection in db

```
> ['john', 'maria', 'tony', 'filip']
```

I don't mind duplicates. Which method is faster?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's run a benchmark!

```
require 'benchmark'


1_200.times { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

Benchmark.bmbm(7) do |bm|
  bm.report('pluck') do
    User.pluck(:email)
  end

  bm.report('pluck.uniq') do
    User.pluck(:email).uniq
  end

  bm.report('only.pluck') do
    User.only(:email).pluck(:email)
  end

  bm.report('only.pluck.uniq') do
    User.only(:email).pluck(:email).uniq
  end

  bm.report('distinct') do
    User.distinct(:email)
  end

  bm.report('only.distnct') do
    User.only(:email).distinct(:email)
  end
end
```

which outputs:

```
Rehearsal ------------------------------------------------
pluck          0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.009913)
pluck.uniq     0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.012156)
only.pluck     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.008731)
distinct       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.004830)
only.distnct   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.005048)
--------------------------------------- total: 0.020000sec

                   user     system      total        real

pluck          0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.007904)
pluck.uniq     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.008440)
only.pluck     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.008243)
distinct       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.004604)
only.distnct   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.004510)
```

it clearly shows that using `#distinct` is almost two times faster than `#pluck`

Comment: I consider this to be low-quality benchmark I did here. Don't use it as final argument anywhere. This benchmark is missing profiling mode (no-caching?) and working on way bigger datasets